# Best way to target 30 different options using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Looking to create an email with 30 different options for an image.  Each image will have a value correspending from 100-130 and there can be up to 3 images per contact in the email - so 3 possible images with a value from 100-130.  The value for the img is a number so for example

101 - img1
103 - img2

Is the best way to tackle this using if statements? like below?

```
%%[
set @img1 

IF @img1 == “101" THEN
 set @imglink = “https://abudhabitiming.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/unspecified1-752x440.jpg”

ENDIF
]%%
<img src="%%=v(@imglink)=%%"
```

Comment: use either a simple loop based on a DE, or even better, dynamic variables; check this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316371/is-there-a-way-to-re-use-ampscript-with-different-variables/316380#316380

Comment: As I wrote to you back in November: So far you have only accepted three of the answers provided to you by the community. It is essential for the way SFSE works, that once a satisfactory answer has been provided, it is being marked as such by the asker. It helps identify the questions with relevant answers. Also it provides a "thank you" to the people who dedicate their time to provide these answers. To ensure your future questions being answered, I will advise you to adhere to [best practices](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on this will be using [ContentImagebyKey](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/contentimagebykey.html) function.
Given you have your customer keys populated properly, like in example below:
[image]

you can use following ampscript:

```
%%[
SET @image = '101'
SET @imagekey = concat('burgers ',@image)
]%%

%%=ContentImagebyKey(@imagekey,'burgers')=%%
```

This will produce following HTML code:

```
<img title="Logo" alt="Logo" src="http://images.example.com/imageofburger101.png" border="0" thid="exampleValue">
```

This will result in the cleanest code, as you will not have to map the values to image URLs neither in your code nor in a mapping data extension. You will need to upload the number of images required (in your example: 30 images) with a unique external key, allowing you to generate the identifier in very few lines of code, as described.

As ContentImageByKey is only returning a very simple img tag, you will need to user Replace function to add the styling as needed, to ensure the correct width of your image, e.g.: `%%=Replace(ContentImagebyKey(@imagekey,"burgers"),'>','style="width:100%;">')=%%`

Comment: Thanks I forgot to mention that this will be a triggered email - does that change anything?

Comment: No, this is the same. Of course you need to pass the data in the payload, and adjust your Ampscript to fetch these values

Comment: Thanks - so there are up to 3 images per customer - so that means 31 different options per image -

Thinking about this it seems like there will be maybe 100 lines of code?  Is there any other shorter way?

WIll try this shortly thank you so much!

Comment: This depends highly on how the selection of images occurs? What is it based on? A single variable? Multiple variables? How many images are there in total? Please update your question with these additional clarifications.

Comment: THanks alot lukas I rephrased my question - one more important question - is there a way to control the size of the img?  I read the description - how can I control the height and width of the img?  Or does the IMG have to be the exact size?

Comment: @GS65 - I have added details to my answer, to elaborate on how to ensure the right image size.

Comment: Hi Lukas I just received some more info - thanks for the info above - it appears that the table will have up to 3 tickets per contact.  So 1 contact key with 3 different entries for each of their emojis - this would require a loop no? to display each unique ticket for that specfic contact - would a look up satisfy this?

So loop through each contact key and output the information needed

Comment: https://ampscript.guide/lookuporderedrows/ I just found this as a possibility, would it work?

Comment: @GS65 I will recommend you to create a new question where you provide ALL these details, along with an example of the data extensions this data will be fetched from, along with your own attempt to write Ampscript printing these images/tickets in email.